# iMovie 10.0.7 How do I mark my "favorite" part of a video and move it into the timeline

Tags: video, imovie, video-editing

Under the old version you could make the part of the video clip you liked and it would show GREEN after you moved it into the the timeline. This version shows the make area in the menu, but does not work. The menu is light gray and there is no "heart" icon on the screen for the "favorite" part of the clip. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can still favorite sections of your clips in iMovie by selecting a portion of your clip in the library and hitting the "F" key. Your selection will be marked by a green bar, like before.